# Problem in finding the string with the largest length and storing it in a list

Tags: python, list, debugging

I have three lists of strings, and I want to find the strings with the largest lengths for each iteration to store their lengths in a list. For example, if I had three lists of strings A, B & C, I would want the length of the largest string for the first iteration to be stored in a list Z. This is the code:

```
x = ['2341', '132', '122322']
z = ['1', '31231', '123']
il = ['89801', '13312312', '840119']
bl = list()

for i, j, k in zip(x, z, il):
    if len(i) >= len(j):
        if len(i) >= len(k):
            bl.append(len(i))
    elif len(j) >= len(i):
        if len(j) >= len(k):
            bl.append(len(j))
    else:
        bl.append(len(k))
print(bl)
```

So, I expected the list bl to be [5, 8, 6], as they are the lengths of the largest string for each iteration, but when I print the output says only [6]. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you did not give `else` statements after `if len(i) >= len(k)` and `if len(j) >= len(k)` Try this

```
x = ['2341', '132', '122322']
z = ['1', '31231', '123']
il = ['89801', '13312312', '840119']
bl = list()

for i, j, k in zip(x, z, il):
    if len(i) >= len(j):
        if len(i) >= len(k):
            bl.append(len(i))
        else:
            bl.append(len(k))
    elif len(j) >= len(i):
        if len(j) >= len(k):
            bl.append(len(j))
        else:
            bl.append(len(k))
    else:
        bl.append(len(k))
print(bl)
```

This is a bit complicated, I'd rather say you use the `max()` like the answer given by [`@lucy_datanalyst`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12658350/lucy-datanalyst)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have over-complicated this.

You can use max() to get max length in each iteration e.g.

```
x = ['2341', '132', '122322']
z = ['1', '31231', '123']
il = ['89801', '13312312', '840119']
bl = list()

for i, j, k in zip(x, z, il):
    bl.append(max(len(i), len(j), len(k)))
print(bl)
```

This prints `[5, 8, 6]` as you expected

Comment: Woah! I forgot about that function. Thanks for the answer!! Could you still explain why my initial code was not working correctly?

Comment: Just seen your comment and was about to add why your code doesn't work but have just seen [@an4s911](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12033855/an4s911) has provided an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As for the solution using list comprehension, the below code takes the max of the length of each element

```
[max(len(x[i]), len(z[i]), len(il[i])) for i in range(len(il))]
```

As for debugging your code, the conditional statements are wrong

```
x = ['2341', '132', '122322']
z = ['1', '31231', '123']
il = ['89801', '13312312', '840119']
bl = list()

for i, j, k in zip(x, z, il):
  print(i,j,k)
  if len(i) >= len(j):
      if len(i) >= len(k):
          bl.append(len(i))
  elif len(j) >= len(i):
      if len(j) >= len(k):
          bl.append(len(j))
  else:
      bl.append(len(k))
  print(bl)
```

out on debugging:

```
2341 1 89801  
[]  
132 31231 13312312  
[]  
122322 123 840119  
[6]
```